# Is there any song content-based feature extraction code?

Tags: audio, metadata

Is there any open-source code can extract content-based music features like tempo, beats, etc.?

My application scenario is like this:

1. A music repository which contains more than 20,000 songs
2. Extract features and auto-tag these songs by the "Program" which could be suggested by you.
3. Auto classify these songs by the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best open-source audio (waveform, etc.) tool for what you're looking for is the jAudio subset of jMIR: http://jmir.sourceforge.net/jAudio.html.  The best tool that you could use for the project, though it's not open-source is free to use, is the EchoNest API.  I am assuming that when you say "music" you mean audio; if it's musical scores, you could use the jSymbolic toolkit of jMIR if the data is MIDI or the .features module of my music21 toolkit if it's another format.

Answer (score 1):

Echonest API is the best. I have used it a lot in my projects. I used this tutorial for learning how to use echonest http://preciselyconcise.com/apis_and_installations/echo_nest.php